# how to get response text in execute method of DispatchAction class

Tags: java, servlets, response, struts

I have extended the `DispatchAction` to create my own `CustomDispatch` class with overriden method of `execute()`.

I want to somehow get hold of the response text that is being written into the `response.getWriter()` in one of the methods defined in the `Action`. I am only able to access the object of `HttpServletResponse` and not the text that was written into the response.

Please help me out.

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose? Once data is written into the writer it may not even be there any more--it's like asking to get the content of a file buffer where it may already have been written to the disk and flushed.

Comment: That is what I was expecting, whether it is like flushing it to a disk or there is some intermediate place where the data gets segregated first and then sent. Got it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ServletResponseWrapper` so that you intercept writes and put them in your own buffer to retrieve as needed.

For example, you could start with:

```
public class WrappingFilter implements Filter
{
    private static final ThreadLocal<StringBuilder> contentBuffer = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        contentBuffer.set(new StringBuilder());
        chain.doFilter(request, new ContentBufferingResponseWrapper(response));
        contentBuffer.remove();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {

    }

    public static StringBuilder getResponse()
    {
        return contentBuffer.get();
    }

    private class ContentBufferingResponseWrapper extends ServletResponseWrapper
    {
        public ContentBufferingResponseWrapper(final ServletResponse response)
        {
            super(response);
        }

        @Override
        public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException
        {
            return new PrintWriter(super.getWriter())
            {
                @Override
                public void write(final String s, final int off, final int len)
                {
                    contentBuffer.get().append(s);
                    super.write(s, off, len);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

You could then call `WrappingFilter.getResponse()` to get a buffer of the response written thus far for the current request.

It is not an elegant solution, and I've not tested it, but hopefully can put you on the right track.

I suggest you have a look at sitemesh, which uses a similar approach to intercept the response into a different buffer so that it can be modified before being written to the response - a little different to what you're trying to do, but the same technique can be applied. https://github.com/sitemesh/sitemesh3/blob/master/sitemesh/src/main/java/org/sitemesh/webapp/contentfilter/HttpServletResponseBuffer.java